# SQL query for each ID in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for 1 particular customer_id. How can I execute this query for each customer_id in table?

```
SELECT      *
FROM        table
WHERE       date <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59' AND customer_id = 100
ORDER BY    date DESC
LIMIT       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.date <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                WHERE t.customer_id = s.customer_id
                AND t.date < s.date)
```

This will select only a record after the date filter where `NOT EXISTS` another record for the same id with a bigger date. Its basically the same as `limit 1` for all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Table) s
ON t.customer_id = s.customer_id
WHERE t.date = '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Don't you want `<=`?